# Mysql lower case table on Windows xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I want to change the lower case table to 0 to write table names with uppercase. I use xampp on windows.

Mysql Workbench show me as configuration file C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
and i added the line

```
lower_case_table_names=0
```

In xampp i changed the C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini with the same line. But still the variable show 1. I dont unterstand why it didnt changed. Maybe someone could help me with the problem. And yes i restart mysql after changing files.

the my.ini in ProgrammData

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

and the my.ini in xampp mysql

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 0
# Set basedir to your installation path
basedir=c:/xampp/mysql

# Set datadir to the location of your data directory
datadir=c:/xampp/mysql/data

# Default: 128 MB
# New: 1024 MB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> You should not set lower_case_table_names to 0 if you are running
>   MySQL on a system where the data directory resides on a
>   case-insensitive file system (such as on Windows or macOS). It is an
>   unsupported combination that could result in a hang condition when
>   running an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM tbl_name operation with the
>   wrong tbl_name lettercase.

**Conclusion**: you can't do that on Windows. You will have to use a Unix or Linux system to set lower_case_table_names to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Enter the Xampp configuration panel and open MySql settings file: "my.ini".

Find section:

"# The MySQL server"

[mysqld]

set (or type):
lower_case_table_names =2

(Note: lower_case_table_names=1  set names to lowercase; while
lower_case_table_names=2 allows uppercase).

(solution source:
https://happilyblogging.wordpress.com/2016/05/04/upper-case-table-names-in-mysql-which-comes-with-xampp/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).