# Can't set lower_case_table_names to 0 on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, configuration, xampp

I'm using XAMPP's MySQL on Win10, when I try to set `lower_case_table_names = 0` the MySQL service just don't start, XAMPP console didn't show me any error messages it just stays like this > 10:04:51 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...

I can set `lower_case_table_names = 2` and there's no problem, but using 0 it just dont work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql lower case table on Windows xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935028/mysql-lower-case-table-on-windows-xampp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Server System Variables  /  `lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> You should **not** set `lower_case_table_names` to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system where the data directory resides on a case-insensitive file system (such as on Windows or macOS).

So when the server doesn't start, it just saves your data...

Comment: I see, thank you a lot for sharing this info!